# Top of the images to be in line with the top image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make images on my page to be tightly under each other so the top of the images is always inline with the previous image.

However, I cannot sort this simple problem out as there is always a gap between the images.

This is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x83ubas9/)

The images only have simple inline CSS which is:

```
width:100%  !important; 
height:100% !important; 
margin:0 !important; 
padding:0 !important;
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image inside div has extra space below the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: @CBroe, yes, correct. I flagged it to be deleted as I cannot delete it myself since it has an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `vertical-align: top` css property to your `img`.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x83ubas9/2/)